# Cypress runner not waiting for page to load before running assertion

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end

I'm using cypress to run end to end tests, and at some point during the scenario, I click on a button that triggers multiple requests to a backend API and to Stripe's API.
Once all the requests are successful, there is a redirection. I'm trying to assert that the URL contains a keyword that would confirm that the redirection was successful.

```
cy.get('[data-cy="payment-form-submit"]').click()
cy.url().should('include', 'somekeyword')
```

Unfortunately, Cypress does not wait for all the request to resolve before evaluating `cy.url()` so the assertion always fails despite the redirect being successful.

I've read in the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Unnecessary-Waiting) that it was supposed to wait, but couldn't verify it in practice. Am I missing something here? How should I solve this?

Comment: how much time does it between button click and redirection?

Answer (score 1):

The `.should()` command will retry the preceding command, which you can see if you run the equivalent with a callback and log each call

```js
cy.url().should(url => {
  console.log(url)                           // 170+ logs in 4 seconds
  expect(url).to.include('somekeyword');
})
```

It is likely you need a longer timeout,

```js
cy.url({ timeout: 10000 }).should('include', 'somekeyword');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should utilise the `as()` method on `cy.intercept` so that you correctly wait for all of the requests to complete before moving on to verify that the URL has changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can try .then() operation, it explicitly waits for the operation to be completed.

```
cy.get('[data-cy="payment-form-submit"]').click().then(()=>{
cy.url().should('include', 'somekeyword')
});
```

https://example.cypress.io/commands/connectors#then